# R is not generated by eclipse

Tags: android

I recently started working on android. I have problem that eclipse does not generate the R java file. Everything is updated. "Build automatically"  is checked and I also cleaned the project. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: updated adt to rev 22?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used to have such error I would delete that R package all together. 
And go through the `XML` file/s that I recently changed and `ctrl+z` it to previous state...

Ecalipse is good for the java portion, but it will not detect errors in the `XML` files. So you have to go manually and look for errors in the code - and be very careful.

After you double and triple check that you have no errors in the xml files, clean and rebuild the project.

On the same note, I heard google came out with a good editor, look into it: [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)

Good luck

Comment: i didn't do any changes in XML files. i just start the project. and error is occurred.

Comment: Did you update eclipse and SDK and everything else? Have you followed the steps [here](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an error in any of your resources?
Eclipse will not generate `R.java` if there are build errors.

Comment: there is no R.java is present in scr folder. and the error is 'R cannot be resolved to a variable' in  mainactivity.java

Answer (score 0):

Go through each one of your `.xml` files, and check to see if you have any errors.

This will be the reason for your `R` file is not building.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many causes for this.

You should first check that your resources in the res folder are not reported to be wrong.

If that's not the case some suggest to restart Eclipse.

If this won't solve then you should open the Android Update manager to see if the Build Tools are installed. You'll likely need these!

When I had this issue I tried Eclipse Galileo with ADT 22.0 and this combination could not work (but there never was a good information in the logs). Once I used Eclipse Juno with ADT 22.0 it worked like a charm.